# Extend screens - 1 VGA Monitor and 1 hdmi Monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

Noob question - If I connect 1 monitor to my PC with a VGA cable, and use a VGA to HDMI cable for the other monitor to PC, will this display the same screen, or can I have two different screens (extend)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will indeed be able to have two seperate outputs on two seperate monitors.